# Calculating Value pro rata over months with Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

Say I have a table containing the term of my user subscriptions, like:

```
user    product    value    start_date    end_date
Scott   T23K       250      15/01/2014    15/02/2015
Tiger   T23K       200      05/01/2014    05/02/2015
Scott   T00Z       20       10/01/2014    02/02/2015
...
```

And I want to build revenue report, based on my billing cycles (monthly) that would look like:

```
month       product    value
Jan/2014    T23K       275
Jan/2014    T00Z       19.1
Feb/2014    T23K       275
Feb/2014    T00Z       0.9
```

I guess I *could* query [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4812e/1), though I was wondering if there wasn't a clever analytic function or something that would make it look nicer. Ideas?

I am using Oracle 11gR2

Comment: How is the value 0.9 calculated for T00Z/February?

Comment: 23 days of term for T00Z, 21 days in Jan. and 2 days in Feb., thus it's value is split as ~95% ($19.1) spent in Jan. and ~5% ($0.9) spent in Feb.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it match your case:

```
with subscriptions as
(
select 'Scott'  user_,  'T23K'  product ,    '250'  value ,    to_date('15/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') start_date ,  to_date('15/02/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') end_date from dual
union all
select 'Tiger'  user_,  'T23K'  product ,    '200'  value ,    to_date('05/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') start_date ,  to_date('05/02/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') end_date from dual
union all
select 'Scott'  user_,  'T00Z'  product ,    '20'  value ,    to_date('10/01/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') start_date ,  to_date('02/02/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') end_date from dual
)
, allMonts as
(select   add_months(to_date('01/01/2010','DD/MM/YYYY'),rownum) myMonth , lag(add_months(to_date('01/01/2010','DD/MM/YYYY'),rownum)) over (order by rownum desc) -add_months(to_date('01/01/2010','DD/MM/YYYY'),rownum) daymonth from dual  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100
)
, detail as
(
select  s.*,allMonts.myMonth, end_date-start_date duration, 
        case when trunc(start_date,'MON')=trunc(end_date,'MON') then (end_date-start_date)*value/( end_date-start_date) 
          when trunc(start_date,'MON')=allMonts.myMonth then (add_months(allMonts.myMonth,1) - start_date)*value/( end_date-start_date) 
          when trunc(end_date,'MON')=allMonts.myMonth then (end_date - allMonts.myMonth )*value/( end_date-start_date)   
          else  allMonts.daymonth*value/( end_date-start_date) 
          end value_by_month
from subscriptions s , allMonts
where allMonts.myMonth
between trunc(s.start_date,'MON') and trunc(s.end_date,'MON')+1
)
select myMonth, product, sum(value_by_month)
from detail
group by rollup(myMonth), product
```